# Pig: Count only specific rows

Tags: count, group-by, apache-pig

I have a data that has `location`, `sentiment` and `brand` fields. I want to calculate the number of positives, negatives and neutrals in a location for a brand.

Assuming `x` has the data, I did:

```
a1 = GROUP x BY (location, brand);
a2 = FOREACH a1 GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (location, brand), COUNT(x.sentiment=="positive"?1:0) AS positive_count, COUNT(x.sentiment=="negative"?1:0) AS negative_count, COUNT(x.sentiment=="neutral:?1:0) as neutral_count;
```

But I am getting a syntax error saying `Unexpected character '"'`

I tried grouping by all three: `location, sentiment and brand` but I am getting only the overall count like:

```
{location: "newyork", brand: "pampers", sentiment = "positive", count = 10}
{location: "newyork", brand: "pampers", sentiment = "negative", count = 2}
{location: "newyork", brand: "pampers", sentiment = "neutral", count = 20}
```

I want seperate fields for positives_count, negatives_count and neutrals_count. Something like this:

```
{location: "newyork", brand: "pampers", positive_count = 10, negative_count = 2, neutral_count = 20}
{location: "london", brand: "pampers", positive_count = 12, negative_count = 0, neutral_count = 35}
{location: "newyork", brand: "huggies", positive_count = 40, negative_count = 6, neutral_count = 10}
```

Can some one help me out please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single quotes

```
a1 = GROUP x BY (location, brand);
a2 = FOREACH a1 GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (location, brand), 
                    COUNT(x.sentiment=='positive'?1:0) AS positive_count, 
                    COUNT(x.sentiment=='negative'?1:0) AS negative_count, 
                    COUNT(x.sentiment=='neutral'?1:0) as neutral_count;
```

**EDIT**

```
newyork pampers positive
newyork pampers positive
newyork pampers negative
newyork pampers positive
newyork pampers positive
newyork pampers neutral
newyork pampers positive
newyork pampers negative
newyork pampers neutral
newyork pampers positive
newyork pampers positive
newyork pampers neutral
```

**Script**

```
B = GROUP A BY (location,brand);
C = FOREACH B  { 
                  A1 = FILTER A BY sentiment matches 'positive';
                  A2 = FILTER A BY sentiment matches 'negative';
                  A3 = FILTER A BY sentiment matches 'neutral';
                  GENERATE FLATTEN(group) as (location,brand),COUNT(A1),COUNT(A2),COUNT(A3);
               };
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: Looks like you just substituted the double quotes with single quotes. I tried that but did not work for me. Threw a syntax error. Anyways, I figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: `mismatched input '==' expecting RIGHT_PAREN`

Answer (score 0):

I filtered the alias that contained the original data and counted each number of entries and joined them all.

```
p = FILTER y BY (sentiment == 'positive');
p1 = GROUP p BY (location, brand, avl_author_type);
p2 = FOREACH p1 GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (location, brand, avl_author_type), COUNT(p) AS positive_counts;

n = FILTER y BY (sentiment == 'negative');
n1 = GROUP n BY (location, brand, avl_author_type);
n2 = FOREACH n1 GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (location, brand, avl_author_type), COUNT(n) AS negative_counts;

ne = FILTER y BY (sentiment == 'neutral');
ne1 = GROUP ne BY (location, brand, avl_author_type);
ne2 = FOREACH ne1 GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (location, brand, avl_author_type), COUNT(ne) AS neutral_counts;

j1 = JOIN p2 BY (location, brand, avl_author_type) LEFT OUTER, n2 BY (location, brand, avl_author_type);
j2 = FOREACH j1 GENERATE p2::location as location, p2::brand as brand, p2::avl_author_type as avl_author_type, p2::positive_counts as positive_counts, n2::negative_counts as negative_counts;

j3 = JOIN j2 BY (location, brand, avl_author_type) LEFT OUTER, ne2 BY (location, brand, avl_author_type);
j4 = FOREACH j3 GENERATE j2::location as location, j2::brand as brand, j2::avl_author_type as avl_author_type, j2::positive_counts as positive, j2::negative_counts as negative, ne2::neutral_counts as neutral;
```

Kind of lengthy but worked.